# Arduino UDPNTP Epoch, determine minute of the day

Tags: c, arduino, epoch

I'm having a little trouble figuring this one out.

There are 1440 minutes per day. I wish to determine, using NTP the current minute of the day, so 12:00pm would be 720, 12:01pm would be 721 etc

I'm executing this on an arduino board using C,

```
const unsigned long seventyYears = 2208988800UL;     
unsigned long epoch = secsSince1900 - seventyYears;
```

I know that `(epoch % 3600 ) / 60` gives me the current minute of the current hour (although its not 100% clear how).

---

**Update**

The anwser below is correct but my results don't make sense:

```
Serial.print("Unix time = ");
const unsigned long seventyYears = 2208988800UL;     
unsigned long epoch = secsSince1900 - seventyYears;  
Serial.println(epoch);
Serial.println((epoch % (3600 * 24))/ 60);
```

```
[Output:]
Unix time = 1427815654
144
```

But When i calculate `(1427815654 % (3600 * 24)) / 60` i get `927` which is what i expect it to be. How the hell, or where the hell did my board get `144` from?

Comment: *although its not 100% clear how* What does that mean? Don't you understand it or are you referring to leap seconds?

Comment: My advise: for any such calculus, go through `struct tm` and `localtime` or `gmtime`. There were irregularities in time between 1970 and today and those two functions can save you a lot of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If `(epoch % 3600 ) / 60` is percise enough to you, you could simply use:

```
(epoch % (3600 * 24)) / 60
```

(However that ignores leap seconds)

---

Explanation

`%` gives the rest of a division.

So we divide all seconds since the epoch by the seconds of a day (`3600 * 24`). We've now got the second of the day, so dividing by 60 gives us the minute.

Comment: This is definitely the right way, but i'm getting incorrect results. i believe it could be something wrong with my original epoch as i'm receiving values of less than 100

Comment: Im unsure why, but your method doen't work at least with arduino UdpNtp Client. Your method gave values of just over a hundred...

`( (((epoch  % 86400L) / 3600) * 60) + (epoch % 3600) / 60 )`

this provided me with what i wanted, simply take number of hours & minutes and work out number of minutes between